# How to specify index storage type in nHibernate / Fluent-nhibernate

Tags: mysql, indexing, hash, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent-nHibernate as ORM with MySQL database in one of my applications.

For certain columns, where I need only equality comparison, I will like to use hashing index type option of MySQL. As per MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html) it is very fast (for the purpose - compared to default btree indexing).

How do I specify in my ClassMap that for the particular column nhibernate should create a hash index instead of default btree index?